# How to generate cucumber html report without overlapping with previous report

Tags: selenium-webdriver, cucumber-junit

I am using Selenium-Cucumber framework. In which i am able to generate html report but it is overlapping with previously generated report. My TestRunner class is given below.

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"./src/test/resources/com/features"},
    glue = {"stepdefinitions", "AppHooks"},
    tags = "@f2",
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber.html",
    "json:target/cucumber.json"}
    )

public class MyTestRunner { 

}
```

So how can i append a time stamp variable at the end of report file name in order to generate report file with unique name.Thanks in advance.